# cygwin ssh connection OK via localhost, but not via 127.0.0.1

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

I've installed Cygwin and OpenSSH server on it.

Cygwin version is 2.2.1(0.289/5/3) and OpenSSH version is 7.0p1-1

After some configuration, I can connect on my SSH server with:

```
$ ssh username@localhost
username@localhost's password:
Last login: Sat Aug 22 13:37:06 2015 from ::1
```

But, I couldn't connect on my SSH server with:

```
$ ssh username@127.0.0.1
username@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
username@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
username@127.0.0.1's password:
Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 2: Too many attempts.
Disconnected from 127.0.0.1
```

I am very confused since I have no idea about what's the difference between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`

For more detail, I've described `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` in [here](https://gist.github.com/gsongsong/7a0f5653f71d73824e8c)

Comment: Basically, if nothing is misconfigured, there should be no difference between these two. What is written in your `hosts` file (not sure where is it in windows)?

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/gsongsong/4adbba73ffa2decc8b34) is the `hosts` file on Windows. Cygwin, the content is the same.